# Scanner driver conflicts with 2 same scanners

Tags: c#, wia

I have this C#, WIA app that I made to control 1+ scanners. Its on Win7

I start a new instance of the app each time I want to control another scanner. This works fine with 2 different scanners, HP and Epson, but when I add another Epson and try to scan with it, it fails. I believe this is due to the drivers being locked by the first Epson scanner. **How do I tell the second Epson scanner to use a different set of drivers?** My thoughts are to copy the first scanners drivers to another location. Then search the registry for the first set of driver files. Then see if I can puzzle out individual scanners. I know that there is a unique ID property for the scanners. Then i would tell the second scanner's ID to use these drivers instead.

I have thought about using a Virtual Machine but don’t want to do that.

Comment: > I start a new instance of the app each time I want to control another scanner... Do you mean you do really start a new app process by 4ex. double-clicking on the icon?

Comment: I open the bin/release folder and double click the exe. I then bind this instance to the first Epson scanner. I then double click the exe again and bind the second instance to the second Epson scanner. I am sure that I have the right scanner b/c i show the scanner's USB location and it's Unique ID and they are different. But when i send commands using WIA to the second scanner they are captured by the first Epson scanner. This app works perfectly with 2 different scanners, I.E. Epson and HP. but when 2 of the same are used then WIA fails to distinguish one from the other.